Website cannot show the data from database on AWS lab
I was doing this lab https://awsacademy.instructure.com/courses/85814/modules/items/7803186 yesterday, then I already finished setting up all the EC2, RDS, Cloud9 environment and etc.
I was able to perform the operation (CRUD) on the website, and also performed load test for the website. However, today, I started the lab, I wanted to try out the website again, then I found out the website could not load the data from the database, it supposed to show a list of students on the Student List section. So, I thought it was the mysql database issue, so I try logging in, which I found out that the data is still accessible, just that the website is unable to display the data.
Image of database data
I would appreciate if anyone could guide me on this
I tried checking the mysql database, checking for the security group.
But all seems to be correct because yesterday I was able to access the website without any errors occurred.
There's no error messages noticed on the database, and ec2 log.
This is the script used for setting up the database
#!/bin/bash -xe
apt update -y
apt install nodejs unzip wget npm mysql-server -y
#wget https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/CUR-TF-200-ACCAP1-1-DEV/code.zip -P /home/ubuntu
wget https://aws-tc-largeobjects.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/CUR-TF-200-ACCAP1-1-79581/1-lab-capstone-project-1/code.zip -P /home/ubuntu
cd /home/ubuntu
unzip code.zip -x "resources/codebase_partner/node_modules/*"
cd resources/codebase_partner
npm install aws aws-sdk
mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'nodeapp' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'student12'";
mysql -u root -e "GRANT all privileges on *.* to 'nodeapp'@'%';"
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS;"
mysql -u root -e "USE STUDENTS; CREATE TABLE students(
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            phone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY ( id ));"
sed -i 's/.*bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
systemctl enable mysql
service mysql restart
export APP_DB_HOST=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
export APP_DB_USER=nodeapp
export APP_DB_PASSWORD=student12
export APP_DB_NAME=STUDENTS
export APP_PORT=80
npm start &
echo '#!/bin/bash -xe
cd /home/ubuntu/resources/codebase_partner
export APP_PORT=80
npm start' > /etc/rc.local
chmod +x /etc/rc.local

Now I need to find out how to make the website get back access to the data.

this is lab right? so they should have stopped/refreshed the services and removed old data

Unfortunately, we cannot view the contents of the Lab with the URL provided (it requires a login). If the script you have shown is passed to the EC2 instance via the 'User Data' field, then it is only executed on first boot. It is possible that the app won't work on subsequent reboots because the export instructions do not run again. So, it might not be written to handle a reboot, but it is difficult to confirm without seeing the lab instructions.

@AshishKamble yes, that means I need to reconfigure the service every time I start the lab?
